# Pandas data precision

Tags: python, pandas

By default the numerical values in data frame are stored up to 6 decimals only. How do I get the full precision.

For example
34.98774564765 is stored as 34.987746. I do want the full value.

and 0.00000565  is stored as 0.

Apart from applying formats to each data frame is there any global setting that helps preserving the precision.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Answer (score 86):

No, `34.98774564765` is merely being printed by default with six decimal places:

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame([34.98774564765])
           0
0  34.987746
```

The data itself has more precision:

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame([34.98774564765])[0].data[0]
34.98774564765
```

You can change the default used for printing frames by altering [`pandas.options.display.precision`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html).

For example:

```
>>> pandas.set_option("display.precision", 8)
>>> pandas.DataFrame([34.98774564765])
                0
0  34.98774564765
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for - thank you. df.round(10) did not work and all other format functions did not work, too. This was perfect & simple.

Comment: This option will sometimes print things in scientific notation. Use the `display.precision` option from the other answer if you need uniform outputs

Comment: It seems to me that `astype` is also affected, so that `column.astype(str)[0]` will be truncated

Comment: I've solved it by doing `c.astype(np.float64).astype(str)`, otherwise a direct conversion from `float32` to string seems to do a kind of "display" conversion and truncates the number

Comment: @Eric Burel … if your data is `float32` then it will only have around 7 significant digits of precision.  Upcasting it to `float64` won’t have added any **real** information at all

Comment: The weird thing is that the data seems to actually have float64 information, as if the data were right, but the "metadata" were wrong (wrongly indicating float32 and thus confusing downstream methods like `astypes`). It's in the context of loading big h5 files in pandas so I still need to double check the dataframe creation process, I didn't manage to reproduce in a unit test.

Answer (score 46):

You can also use the `'display.float_format'` option

```
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:0.20f}'.format):
    print(pd.DataFrame([34.98774564765]))

                        0
0 34.98774564765000150146
```

Comment: this one might be better when you want to avoid the scientific format

Answer (score 12):

Your data is **stored** with the precision, corresponding to your dtype (`np.float16`, `np.float32`, `np.float64`).

`pd.options.display.precision` - allows you to change the precision for `printing` the data

Comment: how do i set this in a context manager?