# Python Pandas Dataframe convert String column to Float while Keeping Precision (decimal places)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

when I convert a column from string to float I lose decimal places, is there a clear way how to keep decimal places?

```
dicti = {'1': ['55.230530663425',
  '43.597357785755'],
 '2': ['25.231784186637',
  '93.59759890623'],
 '3': ['75.229467797447',
  '33.597732846763'],
 '4': ['15.228959922301',
  '33.596897400263'],
 '5': ['95.231278845519',
  '23.599502230125']}


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicti, 'index')
df[0] = df[0].astype(float)
df[1] = df[1].astype(float)
print(df)

           0          1
1  55.230531  43.597358
2  25.231784  93.597599
3  75.229468  33.597733
4  15.228960  33.596897
5  95.231279  23.599502
```

Comment: they are kept, just not printed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the top answer from

[Pandas data precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217916/pandas-data-precision#43217982)

to see how to change the display precision if you want to see more decimal places. As has been said, the full precision is stored, just not displayed.