# I converted a column from object to float and it created extra zeros is there any way to remove them?

Tags: python, pandas

I converted a column from objects to floats and in order for that I had to add zeros for the blank space is there any way to remove the zeros without changing the number. I don't want to round the numbers as I need them to stay the same.

[image: Image 1]
This is how I want it to look.

[image: image 2]
But this is how it looks right now

Comment: Please, share code and not screenshots.

Comment: What is the output of `print(df['FG%'].dtype)` ?

Comment: `pandas.set_option("display.precision", 3)`

Comment: For the first image its 'object' and for the second image 'float'

Comment: Why did you "have" to add zeros for the blank space? Removing the blank space instead seems like it would make more sense...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas data precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217916/pandas-data-precision)

Comment: @Joost I don't think so. Notice how the data is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can split each string by an empty string, join them by `0`, and convert to float:

```
df['FG%'] = df['FG%'].str.split('').str.join('0').astype(float)
```

Comment: I did this using lambda but now I have extra zeros

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: `stats_test['3P%'] = stats_test['3P%'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("", "0"))` I used this because I couldn't just apply the `.astype(float)` to the column

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' '  This was the error I was getting when applying `.astype(float)` without apply lambda