# How to avoid rounding off float values to 6 decimal points in pd.to_numeric()?

Tags: python, pandas, series

When I am using to_numeric() convert my string values to float. The values are getting rounded off. How to avoid it?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['1.1122334455', '2.1112223334444', -3.234234234234324])
print(pd.to_numeric(s))
```

Output:

```
0    1.112233
1    2.111222
2   -3.234234
dtype: float64
```

I want all the decimal values or at least 11 for my requirement. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: see this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217916/pandas-data-precision)

Answer (score 0):

No, its not getting rounded off, that's how it gets printed in the terminal. But if you try to print specific value, you'll see all those digits after decimal:

```py
>>> pd.to_numeric(s).iloc[1]
2.1112223334444
```

And its controlled by `precision` option of `display`:

```py
>>> pd.options.display.precision = 11
>>> pd.to_numeric(s)

0    1.11223344550
1    2.11122233344
2   -3.23423423423
dtype: float64
```

Look at [Available Options](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html#available-options) in pandas docs for more.